# Using RubyMine receiving errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails. I purchased Ruby Mine and installed it on Ubuntu. I followed the installation instructions and when I tried to debug my first project in RubyMine, I get this:

> ```
> Error running Development: test001: Failed to install gems.
> ```
>
> Following gems were not installed: linecache19 (0.5.12): Error
>   installing linecache19: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb ***
>   extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the
>   mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
>   Provided configuration options: --with-opt-dir --without-opt-dir
>   --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>   --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir
>   --ruby=/home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError) from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:92:in
>   `' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:11:in`
>    ' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:6:in
>   `' from  rubygems/custom_require>:33:in`require' from 
>   rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require' from 
>   rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require' from extconf.rb:2:in `' Gem
>   files will remain installed in
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/linecache19-0.5.12
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
>   /home/stormkiernan/Downloads/RubyMine-3.2.4/rb/gems/ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre2.gem:
>   Error installing ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.30.pre2.gem: ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb ***
>   extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the
>   mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.
>   Provided configuration options: --with-opt-dir --without-opt-dir
>   --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>   --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir
>   --ruby=/home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError) from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:92:in`
>    ' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:11:in
>   `' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require' from
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:6:in`
>    ' from  rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require' from 
>   rubygems/custom_require>:33:in`rescue in require' from 
>   rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require' from extconf.rb:2:in` ' Gem
>   files will remain installed in
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/linecache19-0.5.12
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out

Now, just prior to this error, I was prompted with:

> The gem ruby-debug-base19x required by the debugger is not currently
>   installed. Would you like to install it?

I responded "Yes", and it attempted (and I assume failed) to download whatever necessary dependencies the software needed. The window title was "Installing Gems". It was immediately after this window closed that I received the above error.

What do I need to do?

edit: Ruby Env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

edit #2 showing errors:

> $ gem install ruby-debug-base19x Fetching: linecache19-0.5.12.gem
>   (100%) Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR: 
>   Error installing ruby-debug-base19x:  ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension.
>
> ```
>     /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some
>   reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/home/stormkiernan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
>   :29:in `require': no such file
>   to load -- ruby_core_source (LoadError)   from
>   <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'    from
>   extconf.rb:2:in `'
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/linecache19-0.5.12
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /home/stormkiernan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/linecache19-0.5.12/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following from a command prompt instead:

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug-base19x
```

of if you're using rvm (recommended):

```
gem install ruby-debug-base19x
```

EDITED: type this first:  `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

Comment: Both of those did not work: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.8 directory. I tried doing the same thing in super user mode, but then it told me: ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19x: linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. This of course shouldn't be possible because moments before that I used RVM to successfully install ruby 1.9.2...

Comment: try rvm 1.9.2 ―default and then the above gem install

Comment: updated post to show environment. i typed: rvm 1.9.2 and nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: after trying that command it still does not work. i updated my post with the errors.

Comment: not sure then; I would either do a rm -rf ~/.rvm and start fresh with rvm or contact JetBrains to see what they recommend.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems and tried so many options before I came across this:
http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm remove 1.9.2m
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

This resolves the issue with linecache19 rubydebug-19 and openssl:

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error running the following command in ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```